# Marker Animation not working on Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I want to animate a marker on a route defined between  a source and a destination. I got a working example code to understand but it does not seem to be working. When i click on Start Button, I get a javascript error. **Object does not support this property or method** on the line.

```
eol=poly.Distance();
```

Please find the below code. Request you all to please guide if i am missing anything.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Google Maps</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>        
<script src="epoly.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </head>
      <body onunload="GUnload()">

        <div id="controls">
         <form onsubmit="start();return false" action="#">
          Enter start and end addresses.<br />
          <input type="text" size="80" maxlength="200" id="startpoint" value="Briarcrest Rd, 90046" /><br />
          <input type="text" size="80" maxlength="200" id="endpoint" value="Hollywood Hills Rd, 90046@34.11327,-118.39089" /><br />
          <input type="submit" value="Start"  />
         </form>
        </div>

        <div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 500px"></div>
        <div id="step">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="distance">Miles: 0.00</div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

          var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
          map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
          map.setCenter(new GLatLng(0,0),2);
          var dirn = new GDirections();
          var step = 5; // metres
          var tick = 100; // milliseconds
          var poly;
          var poly2;
          var lastVertex = 0;
          var eol;
          var car = new GIcon();
              car.image="caricon.png"
              car.iconSize=new GSize(32,18);
              car.iconAnchor=new GPoint(16,9);
          var marker;
          var k=0;
          var stepnum=0;
          var speed = "";   

          function updatePoly(d) {
            // Spawn a new polyline every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
            if (poly2.getVertexCount() > 20) {
              poly2=new GPolyline([poly.getVertex(lastVertex-1)]);
              map.addOverlay(poly2)
            }

            if (poly.GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex+2) {
               if (poly2.getVertexCount()>1) {
                 poly2.deleteVertex(poly2.getVertexCount()-1)
               }
               poly2.insertVertex(poly2.getVertexCount(),poly.GetPointAtDistance(d));
            } else {
              poly2.insertVertex(poly2.getVertexCount(),poly.getVertex(lastVertex++));
            }
          }

          function animate(d) {
            if (d>eol) {
              document.getElementById("step").innerHTML = "<b>Trip completed<\/b>";
              document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML =  "Miles: "+(d/1609.344).toFixed(2);
              return;
            }
            var p = poly.GetPointAtDistance(d);
            if (k++>=180/step) {
              map.panTo(p);
              k=0;
            }
            marker.setPoint(p);
            document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML =  "Miles: "+(d/1609.344).toFixed(2)+speed;
            if (stepnum+1 < dirn.getRoute(0).getNumSteps()) {
              if (dirn.getRoute(0).getStep(stepnum).getPolylineIndex() < poly.GetIndexAtDistance(d)) {
                stepnum++;
                var steptext = dirn.getRoute(0).getStep(stepnum).getDescriptionHtml();
                document.getElementById("step").innerHTML = "<b>Next:<\/b> "+steptext;
                var stepdist = dirn.getRoute(0).getStep(stepnum-1).getDistance().meters;
                var steptime = dirn.getRoute(0).getStep(stepnum-1).getDuration().seconds;
                var stepspeed = ((stepdist/steptime) * 2.24).toFixed(0);
                step = stepspeed/2.5;
                speed = "<br>Current speed: " + stepspeed +" mph";
              }
            } else {
              if (dirn.getRoute(0).getStep(stepnum).getPolylineIndex() < poly.GetIndexAtDistance(d)) {
                document.getElementById("step").innerHTML = "<b>Next: Arrive at your destination<\/b>";
              }
            }
            updatePoly(d);
            setTimeout("animate("+(d+step)+")", tick);
          }

          GEvent.addListener(dirn,"load", function() {
            document.getElementById("controls").style.display="none";
            poly=dirn.getPolyline();
            eol=poly.Distance();
            map.setCenter(poly.getVertex(0),17);
            map.addOverlay(new GMarker(poly.getVertex(0),G_START_ICON));
            map.addOverlay(new GMarker(poly.getVertex(poly.getVertexCount()-1),G_END_ICON));
            marker = new GMarker(poly.getVertex(0),{icon:car});
            map.addOverlay(marker);
            var steptext = dirn.getRoute(0).getStep(stepnum).getDescriptionHtml();
            document.getElementById("step").innerHTML = steptext;
            poly2 = new GPolyline([poly.getVertex(0)]);
            map.addOverlay(poly2);
            setTimeout("animate(0)",2000);  // Allow time for the initial map display
          });

          GEvent.addListener(dirn,"error", function() {
            alert("Location(s) not recognised. Code: "+dirn.getStatus().code);
          });

          function start() {
            var startpoint = document.getElementById("startpoint").value;
            var endpoint = document.getElementById("endpoint").value;
            dirn.loadFromWaypoints([startpoint,endpoint],{getPolyline:true,getSteps:true});
          }

        }

        // This Javascript is based on code provided by the
        // Community Church Javascript Team
        // http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
        // http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

        //]]>
        </script>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the deprecated (and turned off) [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference):

```
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That is currently being replaced by a wrapper for the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics).  It will only work for simple maps.

And update to the v3 version of epoly, this is the v2 version (unless you modified it yourself).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

[example of animating a marker in v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html)

Comment: Geocodezip : Thanks for the reference. I didnt notice that one. I changed it but still i am getting the error for the working example mentioned by you. The code is not working for me. I downloaded th eploy.js file. I am getting the javascript error GPolygon is undefined.

Comment: epoly is a v2 library.  You need to use the v3 port referenced in [that example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html) (or implement everything natively in v3 yourself)

Comment: I would accept the comment mentioned by geocodezip above as the answer for my query. And yes it is now working fine for me. I had downloaded the wrong epoly.js file.